# Two column table on android

Tags: android, textview

Hey everyone. I'm not big into UI programming so this may be an easy thing I overlooked. I am trying have a screen that shows 8 TextView in a 2 column x 4 row table. And, of course, I want the TextViews, that might have different lengths, to be centered. I tried this in a table layout, for obvious reasons but I feel like this is not the way to do it because it doesn't have much control where I put everything once it is in a row. Should I be using a different combinations of layouts or is there something I overlooked.

I can post my xml file if you really need but this is really more of a concept question than a specific one.

Thanks,
Jake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain why a table layout didn't work in more detail? If you're just trying to center the contents of the cells, you can set the `android:gravity` attribute in the table layout to `"center"`

EDIT: You can set the spacing between items using the `android:padding` attribute ([Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:padding)). There are a number of other attributes in that link you can use to modify the way your table is laid out, as well as table-specific attributes at [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, are there other attributes I have to to turn off in order for it to work?

Comment: Ok, that worked for some reason now, how about putting more space between my columns?

Comment: I've updated my answer with more detailed info and links to documentation you can use to further customize your views.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [apps-for-android's](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/) [`GridLayout`](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Photostream/src/com/google/android/photostream/GridLayout.java). You may have to modify it a bit to get it to do exactly what you want, however, it's probably a good starting point.